# How can I automatically name files being exported based on input parameters

Tags: notebooks, string-manipulation, files-and-directories

I have Mathematica notebook that performs some operation say

```
a=2
b=3
c=5
d=4
```

how do I set the output file after evaluation to be named using the values $2,3,5,\ldots$

like *"2_3_5_4_"* such that the the naming automatically takes the values assigned to `a,b,c d`

Comment: Take a look at `ToString`, `StringJoin` etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your data

```
{a, b, c, d} = RandomInteger[9, 4];
data = a b c d;
```

Exporting with nice file-names featuring date and variable values using [`StringTemplate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringTemplate.html)

```
Export[
 StringTemplate[
  "Date`1`_Values_a`2`_b`3`_c`4`.txt"
  ][DateString[{"Year", "Month", "Day"}], a, b, c]
 , data]
```

> ```
> "Date20141201_Values_a7_b5_c3.txt"
> ```

Or using [`ToString`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ToString.html) and  [`StringJoin`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringJoin.html) as suggested by @Kuba

```
 Export[
  StringJoin["Data_", ToString /@ Riffle[{a, b, c, d}, "_"], ".txt"]
 , data]
```

> ```
> "Data_7_5_3_7.txt"
> ```

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple way if you are using the `Table[]` function. For example: ``` Table[Export[NotebookDirectory[]<>ToString@StringForm["test``.txt", l], Table[{l,l^2}, {l, 1, 10}]; ```. In this case, the program will generate ten files written as "testl.txt" for each `l` with the values `l` and `l^2` as columns.